# Transparent colors draw lines with weird artifacts

Tags: java, draw, graphics2d

I have a code example that produces weird results when trying to draw lines with semitransparent colors. This only seems to happen for lines with an "upward" direction. I'm using an older JDK 1.8.0_102, but the issue is also reproduced on JDK 13.0.1. This sure seems like a bug, but maybe there's an explanation?

EDIT: The "weird artifacts" from the title are better described as "double width". Please read the comments below the question for more detail. TLDR; the problem persists - a weird behavior IS reproduced with the below code.

```java
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(46, 46, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
graphics.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

graphics.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 255));
graphics.drawLine(5, 20, 20, 5);
graphics.drawLine(25, 5, 40, 20);

graphics.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 128));
graphics.drawLine(5, 40, 20, 25);
graphics.drawLine(25, 25, 40, 40);

graphics.dispose();
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("image.png"));
```

The result from this is the following image:

[image]

EDIT #2: During further investigation, I tried setting the Graphics2D stroke property of width 2, in hopes it would at least get me consistent behavior, but unfortunately, I was greeted with more inconsistency - "uppward" lines are arguably 2 pixels wide, while "downward" lines seem to be 3 pixels wide. This is the output of simply adding this line before drawing anything:

```
graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I introduced the bug when I was "preparing" the code chunk for posting here. I modified the code and re-uploaded the image - the weird "double thickness" persists.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see anything in the question that said you were talking about a "double thickness". I still don't.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't. Here's what happened. I found the weird behavior while working on small lines, 5x5, and it seemed like "double thickness". I then modified the code to post here and decided to enlarge the lines to make them more visible. Then I noticed the "double thickness" is gone, but the "artifacts" appeared, so I wrongly concluded that on smaller scales the "artifacts" are short enough to be indistinguishable to "double thickness", so I wrote the question as such. But the artifacts were due to the bug in my code, and it was "double thickness" all along.